# js object problem

Tags: javascript, object

I use an object to check that a group of radio buttons have a precise value like set on "rule" object.  Here is an example:

```
arr = {a:"1", b:"1", c:"1", c:"2"}; //that's my object rule

var arr2={}; //here  I create my second array with charged value 
$("#form_cont input:checked").each(function()
{
    arr2[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).val();
});
//here I make the check
for (k in arr2)
{
    if (typeof arr[k] !== 'undefined' && arr[k] === arr2[k]) 
    {
        $("#form_cont li[name$='"+k+"']").css('background-color', '');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#form_cont li[name$='"+k+"']").css('background-color', 'pink');
    }
}
```

The problem is when I have to check the "c" key I get last the one (2) and not the right value how that may e 1 or 2

thanks in advance

ciao, h.

Comment: can you change the 2nd c key to d?

Comment: no I'm sorry c is the radio name that may assume value 1 or 2 :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have more than one value, `arr`'s property `c` will need to be an array:

```
arr = {a:["1"], b:["1"], c:["1","2"]}; //that's my object rule
```

Of course, your validity check must also change to search the new array:

```
typeof arr[k] !== 'undefined' && contains(arr[k], arr2[k])
```

...

```
function contains(a, obj){
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] === obj){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for answering Do i modify my for loop to get c value or not?

Comment: @haltman: No, the rest of your code should work properly as-is.

Comment: I get error on this row in IE: typeof arr[k] !== 'undefined' && contains(arr[k], arr2[k])
Do you have some idea to resolve it?

Comment: @Eric Mickelsen I've tested on IE7 and error is 'undefined' is empty or not an object thanks again ciao h.

Comment: Like often happen problem was in another point thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two properties on an object that are named the same. Thus when the javascript compiler sees the line `arr = {a:"1", b:"1", c:"1", c:"2"};` it automatically changes it to `arr = {a:"1", b:"1",  c:"2"};` letting the last definition of c overwrite the first one

Comment: can I make c in an array and concat in my existing object? can it work?